# Is there a pure Java way of extracting files from InstallAnywhere EXEs?

Tags: java, compression

As part of creating a repository for installers and other build artifacts I am looking at extracting information from Windows EXE files created by [InstallAnywhere](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/producer/products/software-installation/installanywhere/). The basic idea is to read some property files inside the EXE to look for build information that can be used as metadata in the repository.

These open in [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), and I can find the files I am looking for. Obviously I could call out to 7zip for extraction, but I would much prefer a pure Java solution.

Is there a way of extracting files from these kind of EXEs without leaving the Java world?

Comment: If it opens in 7zip is it a zip file? Or does 7zip have specific support for this file type? In any case, if you can figure out the file format (if not zip) then sure, you can read anything. If it's zip,  use the stock zip processing stuff.

Comment: @DaveNewton: it doesn't seem to be a zip file, a ZipInputStream gives me  an empty iteration (which seem to be the normal behaviour for non-zip files)